# Graph of two functions related

Tags: pgfplots

I wanted to draw following graph of two function in which lower line is y=\2sqrt{5}(x-1) and lower line is 2(2x-1). Also I want to denote the upper line by P(T'(M_n)) and lower line by P(M_2n). Axes labels are n for x-axis and P(G) for y-axis.

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you include a minimal working example (MWE) of what you have done so that we know what packages you prefer to use.

Comment: I had taken this snap from graph plotting website. I dont have any Idea how to draw in latex.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Surely you could have a first stab yourself starting from one of the answers to your earlier question [Plot Graph with axis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285204/106162)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to your question [Plot Graph with axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285204/plot-graph-with-axis) should guide you to a starting point for solutions in PGFplots, Metapost and pstricks. Here is a Tikz version.

BTW your functions and plots differs in a factor 2.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3mm,y=1mm]
  \draw[thin,gray!40,xstep=2,ystep=5] (6,5) grid (50,100);
  \draw(5,0) -- (5,100) -- ++(0.5,0)node[anchor=south west]{$P(M_{2n})$};
  \foreach \y in {5,10,...,95}{
    \draw(5,\y)--+(0.5,0)node[right=-2pt]{\footnotesize\textsf{\y}};
  }
  \draw(5,0) -- (50,0) node[anchor=north west]{$n$} -- ++(0,1.5);
  \foreach \x in {6,8,...,48}{
    \draw(\x,0)--+(0,1.5)node[above=-2pt]{\footnotesize\textsf{\x}};
  }
  \begin{scope}
    \clip(5,0) rectangle (50,100);
    \draw[blue,thick] (5,2*5-1) -- node[pos=.7,below,sloped,black]{$2x-1$} (50,2*50-1);
    \draw[red,thick] (5,2.2361*5-2.2361) -- node[pos=0.7,sloped,above,black]{$\sqrt{5}(x-1)$} (50, 2.2361*50-2.2361);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir. No words I have for you. Thank you once again.